# How come using setLevel: won't make the window higher than a full screen game?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Most games (if not all) do not use Lion's full screen feature. They make themselves full screen using an unofficial method. The problem is - no matter how high I set the level of a window (I'm currently using level 25 - making the window higher than the status bar and its icons) it won't appear over the game. I want to achieve an effect similar to Steam's full screen overlay in game. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full-screen games typically aren't windows at all. Most such applications are using CoreGraphics to capture the display (see [`CGDisplayCapture`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html)), bypassing window compositing entirely. (So you can't display content on top of them.) Note that this is perfectly "official" -- it's just a different approach from full-screening a window.

Steam works by having the Steam launcher inject code into the application to display the status popup. It isn't a technique that can -- or should -- be used in more general cases.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there any example code that would show me how to inject such code into an app? Would I need to use Carbon?

Comment: [`mach_inject`](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_inject). But note that it requires user authorization if you didn't launch the victim process yourself (like Steam does), and runs a significant risk of crashing the victim if you aren't really careful. Don't do it.